# How do you turn off AirPlay on ipad3?I'm trying to watch Netflix in my car but it just shows a tv box and says "you are now watching on your tv"

Tags: video, airplay, netflix

As stated I'm trying to watch Netflix in my car. Called Netflix they say to turn off AirPlay on my iPad. Can't find it anywhere on my iPad. Is there a way to do this? It's weird if I move the search button it shows were I am in the show.

Comment: Can you clarify why the fact that you're in your car is relevant? Are you trying to play the audio over your speakers? Have you tried using Bluetooth?

Comment: I'm riding thru Los Angeles and before I left home I downloaded some shows from Netflix to watch. When I try to watch them from my iPad it only shows a picture of a tv and says you are now watching on you tv. I'm in my car nowhere near a tv. Just checked my operating system and its not 10! Thanks JBallin I checked and yes my iPad can't download the new 10 because it doesn't support it. Any way of doing this without updating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn off airplay on iOS 10 you swipe up from the bottom of the screen and then swipe to the right. At the bottom of that view you'll see a triangle icon with circles, click that and change the source to iPad.

Comment: Thanks JBallin I checked and yes it doesn't show the new iOS 10.  my iPad 3 can't download the new 10 because it doesn't support it. Any way of doing this without updating system? – CJ9111 2 mins ago   edit

Comment: It should still work about the same even with an old OS. Additionally you may see a TV icon within Netflix itself, try clicking that and switching to iPad.